# Remove multiple indices of a string

Tags: python, string

What would be a good and short approach to remove a list of indices from a string?

The point is, if I remove a char at index, the indices of the string shift. In this case I would need to shift all the indices in the list, too. Is this the right way or is there a more straight forward approach?

Comment: Are you just asking how to remove characters from a string?

Comment: Using the thoughts you have, either use negative indexes that index from the end of the string, or remove from last to first and you won't have to deal with shifts.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson from last to first is a good thing to have in mind to avoid shifting

Comment: Strings in Python are not like strings in other languages; so your question about moving indices does not apply in Python.

Answer (score 15):

Strings are immutable. So deleting elements from it will not work.

```
data = "Welcome"
del data[0]
# TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item deletion
```

The best way is to reconstruct the string without the elements from the specific indexes and join them together, like this

```
data, indexes = "Welcome", {1, 3, 5}
print "".join([char for idx, char in enumerate(data) if idx not in indexes])
# Wloe
```

Note that the `indexes` is a set of numbers, since sets offer faster lookup than the lists. If you have a list of numbers like `[1, 3, 5]` and if you want to convert them to a set, use `set` function to do that, like this `set([1, 3, 5])`

Comment: Why is it the best way?

Comment: @MxyL This is the straight forward and less complicated way to do this.

Comment: Downvoter, I would like to know what is wrong and how I can improve this answer. Please explain it to me.

Comment: You don't need the inner list.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yup, but lists are faster to join than the generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin `bytearray` for this

```py
def delete(string, indices):
    z = bytearray(string.encode())
    for i in sorted(indices, key=abs, reverse=True):
        del z[i]
    return z.decode()

delete('Hello world!', [0, -3])
```

`'ello word!'`

Beware that this will only work for ascii character strings where the str -> byte mapping is one-to-one.